# I cant receive payments on database Stripe Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, database, stripe-payments

I cannot receive any payment data on my database , im using spatie Laravel webhook client:https://github.com/spatie/laravel-webhook-client.
This is my ChargeSucceededJob.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs\StripeWebhooks;
use App\Models\Payment;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Spatie\WebhookClient\Models\WebhookCall;

class ChargeSucceededJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $webhookCall;
    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function __construct(WebhookCall $webhookCall)
    {
        $this->webhookCall = $webhookCall;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $charge = $this->webhookCall->payload['data']['object'];
        $user = auth()->user();
        if ($user) {
            Payment::create([
                  'user_id' => $user->id,
                  'stripe_id' =>$charge['id'],
                  'amount' => $charge['amount'],
                  'product_id' =>$charge['currency'],
        
              ]);
        }
        // you can access the payload of the webhook call with `$this->webhookCall->payload`
    }
}
```

Can you please provide some help concerning this issue ? , the webhook is working succesfully in stripe webhooks, but i cannot receive the payment on my database

Comment: Do you mean the hook gets run but the database does not get updated?

Comment: @RiggsFolly the charge is successful in stripe webhooks but i cannot receive the payment details in database

Comment: Add some logging here to find out how far it's going. `Log::info(__FILE__.':'.__LINE__);` inside of your construct and a few places inside of your handle will let you know where it's going